# General return type - Java

Tags: java, command, design-patterns

My question is based around invoking a server method by using the command pattern. However there are many possible commands. I would like to introduce a return type for the 'execute' method of each command instance. I know this is not the intended use of the command pattern, but I haven't any other choice. I need to tailor the command pattern to work for me.

For the method signature of the 'execute' method in each command, what could I possibly have as the return type? I'm guessing it would have to be a covariant return type. It's not an ideal solution but I haven't many other options. I'm developing a server for my android app and RMI isn't available in the Android SDK. I would appreciate any advice about the return type issue. I would need to take account of all of the return types that could be returned from all of the different commands. I'm not sure if there is a pattern out there for this issue of returning some sort of generic return type.

I have already looked at this thread:
[command pattern returning status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154935/command-pattern-returning-status)
but I need more inspiration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I probably don't understand the real question here, but this sounds straightforward.

```
public interface Command<T> {
  T execute();
}
```

And then teh commands could be:

```
public class FooCommand implements Command<Bar> {

  public Bar execute() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Or is there a catch somewhere?

Comment: Perfect - Generics. I'm out of touch! Sorry. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you really want is RMI, which Android doesn't support.

You can try to use a lightweight RMI.

To implement something yourself, start from biziclop's interface,

```
// suppose there are object input/output streams established

// on client side
FooCommand foo = new FooCommand(params..);
Bar bar = remoteExec( foo );

<T> T remoteExec(Command<T> cmd)
     output.writeObject(cmd);
     return (T)input.readObject();

// on server side

    Command cmd = (Command)input.readObject();
    Object result = cmd.execute();
    output.writeObject(result);
```

Comment: Hi there. Are there any lightweight RMI libraries out there? If so, I haven't had any luck finding them...

Comment: Looks good! I would imagine that the remoteExec is defined in the Command interface (abstract class), correct? Thanks a mill.

Comment: I don't know, RMI is not in fashion recently. The idea is to use java.lang.reflect.Proxy, intercepting a method call, serialize it to server. Not too hard either. Maybe a worthy open source project for Android.

Comment: I would put remoteExec as a static method somewhere, but you could turn it into an instance method on AbstractCommand.

Comment: I owe you a Guinness! Thanks for the help

Comment: Oh, one last thing, what's biziclop's interface? I've googled it but not found a solid result for it. Thanks

Comment: I mean the interfaces in the answer above mine, posted by "biziclop"